# What do the small black stars mean on my Flaaffy?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I caught it, it had three tiny stars to the left of the CP and it’s light pink, not the regular color

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The stars represent a shiny Pokémon. If you have two of the same Pokémon (especially a species where the shiny looks a lot different than the regular), it’s really easy to see this:

[image: dratini]

[image: ampharos]

Comment: P.S. This is VERY rare

Answer (score 10):

The three stars by the Pokémon indicates that it is a “Shiny”. These Pokémon just have alternates colors than the normal counter parts.

You can see all of your shinies by using the “Shiny” filter on the top right of your Pokémon list

[image: List of shinies]